# Android OnLoadFinished() not called when cursor changes

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I have created a simple  `Activity` which implements the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` interface.
The `OnCreateLoader()` is straightforward:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "On create loader");

    Uri queryUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(SmartPresentationMessage.Person.CONTENT_URI, 1);
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, queryUri, null, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}
```

This method is called when I call `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this)` when the `Activity` is created.

My problem is that on my `ContentProvider`, which has the following `query()` method:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String where,
        String[] whereArgs, String sortOrder)
{
    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

    Cursor queryCursor;
    SQLiteDatabase mdb = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    switch (match)
    {
        case PERSON:
            long personID = ContentUris.parseId(uri);

            queryCursor = mdb.query(TABLE_NAME, projection,
                        SmartPresentationMessage.Person._ID + " = " + personID,
                        whereArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

            asyncQueryRequest("" + (taskTag ++ ) , QUERY_URI + "/" + "person");

            return queryCursor;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported uri: " + uri);
    }
}
```

the `queryCursor` gets updated in the database after a I get a response from a webserver.
However, when I call the `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)` method in the `ContentProvider`'s update method,
my `OnLoadFinished()` method on the `Activity` is not called, even though the uri is identical to the one used when instantiating the `CursorLoader`.

This is the update method on the `ContentProvider`:

```
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where, String[] whereArgs)
{
    //getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);


    // insert the initialValues into a new database row
    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int affected;
    try
    {
        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri))
        {
            case PERSON:
                long personID = ContentUris.parseId(uri);;
                affected = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values,
                        SmartPresentationMessage.Person._ID + " = " + personID,
                        whereArgs);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        db.close();
    }

    return affected;
}
```

Can somebody tell me what could be the cause of my `OnLoadFinshed()` method not being called when calling `notifyChange()` on the same uri?

Thank you, 
Cristi

Answer (score 10):

Before returning your `Cursor` in your provider's `query()` method you'll need to call the following method

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(contentResolver, uri);
```

You can get the `ContentResolver` via a `Context`. In a `ContentProvider` there's a method `getContext()` for this.